# multidimensional array function outputting garbage?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I have this function meant to initialize a multidimensional 2d (6x6) array to zero. I call the function in main using cout to test it and it outputs garbage. Please help. Thanks!

```
int** initializeArray(void)
{
    typedef int* rollArray;     //this line is actually outside of the function in my
                                //program
int i, j;
rollArray *m = new rollArray[6];

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    m[i] = new int[6];

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        m[i][j] = 0;

return m;
}
```

Comment: Fix your code indentation please

Comment: You are initializing a one dimensional array...

Comment: Include your test code that outputs garbage.

Answer (score 1):

If the value 6 is known at compile-time, I would suggest using `std::array` in a nested fashion.  For example:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<int,6>,6> a = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << a[i][j] << std::endl; // Prints 0.
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In fact, you won't even need to create a function to initialize your array.  Declare your nested array and you are good to go.  (If you don't know the dimension at compile-time, you could use `std::vector` in a similar fashion.)

Comment: Even better, you can use ranged-for loops to print it.

Comment: True...how much C++11 should we introduce at once? :)

Comment: As much as is needed to write safer or more readable code imo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your test.
How can you mess up such a simple test? Just use:

```
int ** a = initializeArray();
int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        cout << a[i][j] << " "; 
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```